# How do we express repeating numbers in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, digits, regexp-like

I have a field with an id value.

a ) The value of this field cannot be values ​​like 0, 00000000, 99999999. How do I express this in oracle? Will I do it with Regex?

b ) The field cannot be all letters and cannot contain characters such as periods or commas.
I did the option a as follows but is it true?

select x_ID
from   table1
where  regexp_like(x_ID,'[a-zA-Z]')

edit :  It is not desired to consist of the same number value, for example 77777777. It cannot be shorter than 3 characters in length, for example 0, 12, 11. However, it can have a value like 12345678. AbCdEf or ABCDEF is wrong. Because it is not wanted to consist only of letters. It would be true if it was AbCdEf1 or ABCDEF1 because it also contains a numerical value. I will state all of these conditions as a separate condition in the query.
1- not null
2- The length of the x_ID field cannot be less than 3.
and two more conditions I wrote above.

Comment: . . And why not 0?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some examples of values which are allowed, as well as more examples which are not allowed. From b) I'd think that "aBcDeF" would not be allowed; nor would "A1B2.C3", "D,4", or "X11Y", while from a) I'd think that "123456" would be legal while "1223456" would not. Your regex would allow "aBcDeF" but would not allow the others although perhaps not for the reasons you'd want. Also, as @GordonLinoff has already asked, why is "0" not allowed? It's just a single digit. ???

Comment: You probably need to expand your question with a representative list of allowed / disallowed values, so it is clearer which logic you want to implement.

Comment: I updated my question, I apologize for writing the parts that I could not solve myself :)

Answer (score 1):

> The value of this field cannot be values ​​like 0, 00000000, 99999999. How do I express this in oracle? Will I do it with Regex?

You can use the regular expression `^(.)\1*$` to detect strings that consist solely of one-or-more repetitions of a single character:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( id, '^(.)\1*$' );
```

---

If you want to add conditions to a column then you can add constraints for each one. Some examples could be:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT id_longer_than_2
  CHECK ( LENGTH( id ) > 2 );
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT id_must_contain_lower_case
  CHECK ( REGEXP_COUNT( id, '[[:lower:]]' ) > 0 );
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT id_must_contain_upper_case
  CHECK ( REGEXP_COUNT( id, '[[:upper:]]' ) > 0 );
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT id_must_contain_digit
  CHECK ( REGEXP_COUNT( id, '[[:digit:]]' ) > 0 );
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT id_must_not_repeat
  CHECK ( NOT REGEXP_LIKE( id, '^(.)\1+$' ) );
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT id_is_only_alphanumeric
  CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE( id, '^[[:alnum:]]+$' ) );
```